# Adding ServiceMonitor to existing Express microservice not being registered in Prometheus

Tags: express, kubernetes, prometheus, k3s, servicemonitor

I'm trying to setup monitoring for my microservices and I've created a simple microservice just to try out the Prometheus monitoring. But I'm running into issues of prometheus not registering the service.

I'm deploying an example service like so:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pinger-svc
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pinger-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pinger-svc
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: pinger-svc
        image: pingerservice:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
            protocol: TCP
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name:  pinger-svc
  labels:
    app: pinger-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app:  pinger-svc
  type:  NodePort
  ports:
  - name: web
    port:  80
    targetPort:  3000
    nodePort: 32333
```

And trying to setup a service monitor with:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-pinger-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pinger-svc
  endpoints:
    - port: web
      path: /metrics
      interval: "10s"
```

In the app I'm also exposing the metrics in the app at endpoint `/metrics`:

```
const promBundle = require('express-prom-bundle');
const metricsMiddleware = promBundle({includeMethod: true});

app.use(metricsMiddleware);
```

This is all I can see under the targets at the Prometheus endpoint:
[image]

Here's my prometheus-operator pod config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-cb55c97b9-4rh4f
  generateName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-cb55c97b9-
  namespace: default
  uid: c3c710b9-868f-41d9-b35e-7d55a212dd6f
  resourceVersion: '176924'
  creationTimestamp: '2021-09-16T13:34:16Z'
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-operator
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 18.0.8
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-18.0.8
    heritage: Helm
    pod-template-hash: cb55c97b9
    release: prometheus
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: ReplicaSet
      name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-cb55c97b9
      uid: 62dbdb1e-ed3f-4f6f-a4e6-6da48d084681
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
  managedFields:
    - manager: k3s
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2021-09-16T13:34:47Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:generateName': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:app': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/instance': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/part-of': {}
            'f:app.kubernetes.io/version': {}
            'f:chart': {}
            'f:heritage': {}
            'f:pod-template-hash': {}
            'f:release': {}
          'f:ownerReferences':
            .: {}
            'k:{"uid":"62dbdb1e-ed3f-4f6f-a4e6-6da48d084681"}':
              .: {}
              'f:apiVersion': {}
              'f:blockOwnerDeletion': {}
              'f:controller': {}
              'f:kind': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:uid': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:containers':
            'k:{"name":"kube-prometheus-stack"}':
              .: {}
              'f:args': {}
              'f:image': {}
              'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:ports':
                .: {}
                'k:{"containerPort":10250,"protocol":"TCP"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:containerPort': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:protocol': {}
              'f:resources': {}
              'f:securityContext':
                .: {}
                'f:allowPrivilegeEscalation': {}
                'f:readOnlyRootFilesystem': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
              'f:volumeMounts':
                .: {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/cert"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:readOnly': {}
          'f:dnsPolicy': {}
          'f:enableServiceLinks': {}
          'f:restartPolicy': {}
          'f:schedulerName': {}
          'f:securityContext':
            .: {}
            'f:fsGroup': {}
            'f:runAsGroup': {}
            'f:runAsNonRoot': {}
            'f:runAsUser': {}
          'f:serviceAccount': {}
          'f:serviceAccountName': {}
          'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
          'f:volumes':
            .: {}
            'k:{"name":"tls-secret"}':
              .: {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:secret':
                .: {}
                'f:defaultMode': {}
                'f:secretName': {}
        'f:status':
          'f:conditions':
            'k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Initialized"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Ready"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
          'f:containerStatuses': {}
          'f:hostIP': {}
          'f:phase': {}
          'f:podIP': {}
          'f:podIPs':
            .: {}
            'k:{"ip":"10.42.0.53"}':
              .: {}
              'f:ip': {}
          'f:startTime': {}
  selfLink: >-
    /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-cb55c97b9-4rh4f
status:
  phase: Running
  conditions:
    - type: Initialized
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-09-16T13:34:16Z'
    - type: Ready
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-09-16T13:34:46Z'
    - type: ContainersReady
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-09-16T13:34:46Z'
    - type: PodScheduled
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-09-16T13:34:16Z'
  hostIP: 192.168.50.85
  podIP: 10.42.0.53
  podIPs:
    - ip: 10.42.0.53
  startTime: '2021-09-16T13:34:16Z'
  containerStatuses:
    - name: kube-prometheus-stack
      state:
        running:
          startedAt: '2021-09-16T13:34:46Z'
      lastState: {}
      ready: true
      restartCount: 0
      image: 'quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator:v0.50.0'
      imageID: >-
        quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator@sha256:ab4f480f2cc65e98f1b4dfb93eb3a41410036359c238fdd60bb3f59deca8d522
      containerID: >-
        containerd://4f03044b1013f18f918034e96950908ee3fc31f8de901a740a8594b273b957bc
      started: true
  qosClass: BestEffort
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: tls-secret
      secret:
        secretName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission
        defaultMode: 420
    - name: kube-api-access-6rbnp
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - path: namespace
                  fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        defaultMode: 420
  containers:
    - name: kube-prometheus-stack
      image: 'quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator:v0.50.0'
      args:
        - '--kubelet-service=kube-system/prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet'
        - '--localhost=127.0.0.1'
        - >-
          --prometheus-config-reloader=quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader:v0.50.0
        - '--config-reloader-cpu-request=100m'
        - '--config-reloader-cpu-limit=100m'
        - '--config-reloader-memory-request=50Mi'
        - '--config-reloader-memory-limit=50Mi'
        - '--thanos-default-base-image=quay.io/thanos/thanos:v0.17.2'
        - '--web.enable-tls=true'
        - '--web.cert-file=/cert/cert'
        - '--web.key-file=/cert/key'
        - '--web.listen-address=:10250'
        - '--web.tls-min-version=VersionTLS13'
      ports:
        - name: https
          containerPort: 10250
          protocol: TCP
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - name: tls-secret
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /cert
        - name: kube-api-access-6rbnp
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator
  serviceAccount: prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator
  nodeName: ubuntu
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 65534
    runAsGroup: 65534
    runAsNonRoot: true
    fsGroup: 65534
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
  priority: 0
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
```

Comment: Can you please check your prometheus operator setup, if it scans all namespaces or just the operator namespace.

Comment: @Manuel Added the config for the operator pod. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm, sorry. That was somehow wrong. What i wanted to figure out was, IF the prometheus operator is scanning all namespaces for podmonitor and servicemonitor crds. What you could try is to deploy the servicemonitor once into the namespace where the prometheus operator is running as well. If it is visible then, the configuration could be wrong then and it just scans in the same namespace.

Comment: @Manuel I'm a bit unsure how and where to find where the config for the operator is and where it says what it scans. I installed it via a helm chart for `kube-prometheus-stack-18.0.8 `. They are all deployed in the default namespace as of now, both the prometheus operator and the service monitor.

Comment: Interesting. I just checked my servicemonitor. And i don't see so much differences except that i'm using targetPort instead of port (which is the port of the pod) and that my service itself is type of ClusterIP.

Comment: Did you already figure out, what was the issue?